# Geometry between Cylinders and Cuboids

Tags: modeling, geometry

I'm currently getting started with Blender and Substance.
Since i wanted to test my materials on a model, i tried to create a grenade as it has both square and circular shapes. However, exactly this is my problem now.

If i want to join both the bolt (cylinder, top left) and the base (truncated cone, bottom) with the body (cuboid, center) i would have to subdivide the body in many parts, resulting in the grid-like pattern which you can see in the first picture.
Connecting them using tris (2nd pciture) results in less additional geometry, but causes more problems later on; most notably when using the subsurf-modifier.

**What is the best way to connect the meshes in this situation?**
Thanks for your answers

[image: The "right" way: both vertical an hozontal lines required]
[image: Connected using tris]

Comment: The topology depends on the puropose of the modeling. You can minimize the policount or you can have good deformation... there is no absolute right or wrong. What will this model used for?

Comment: Right now, i want to get used to the workflow between Blender (modelling), Substance Desinger (creating Materials), Substance Painter (Texturing) and Blender (again, rendering).

Comment: ---Thus, policount shouldn't be a problem here, but i still want to have a clean mesh before i can apply a susbsurf-modifier to it. And #1 doesn't look quite like what i'd expect to be one :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Match face-count and keep the flow of the edges

Assuming that you would like to create a sort of "basemesh" to start to work with, I suggest you should:

- keep a the polycount low, it will be faster to make adjustement
- keep a **quad** oriented topology, it increase the edgeflow redabilty and helps to keep the model "clean"
- keep a **quad** oriented topology, because you said you are going to subsurf the model, and quads give best results
- work with the **subsurf** modifier so you can easily check if everithing is going the way you are expecting and to place correct additional edge loops

Here's a possible topology fort this particular case with the previous characteristics:

[image]

Notice how three of the 8 faces that makes the cylinder are "bridged" to other 3 faces of the the other mesh. This allow a good junction between the pieces like they were welded that will give good results once the mesh is being subsurfed.

[image]

Here's the final result with subsurf in action:

[image]